# PHP: get value from subarray

Tags: php, arrays

How do I get the value from a subarray?  In this case I'm interested in the `locale`

```
$objects=
Array
(
    [1397300927159026] => Array
        (
            [category] => 2
            [locale] => de_DE
        )
    [10152395537445743] => Array
        (
            [category] => 100
            [locale] => en_US
        )
)
```

Desired Output:

```
Array
(
    [1397300927159026] => "de_DE"
    [10152395537445743] => "en_US"
)
```

I've tried using a foreach loop to iterate through but the results are a mess -- thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Just a simple foreach would suffice. You just need to create it in another array. Consider this example:

```
$objects = array(
    '1397300927159026' => array('category' => 2, 'locale' => 'de_DE'),
    '10152395537445743' => array('category' => 100, 'locale' => 'en_US'),
);

$new_objects = array();
foreach($objects as $key => $value) {
    // $key will contain = 1397300927159026, and 1397300927159026
    // set that key into the new array as key also 
    $new_objects[$key] = $value['locale'];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_objects);
echo '</pre>';
```

Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [1397300927159026] => de_DE
    [10152395537445743] => en_US
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what `array_map()` is for. It loops through the array and applies a callback function to each value and returns the modified array.

```
$objects = array_map( function( $val ) {
    return $val['locale'];
}, $objects );
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, don't just write code, so the OP can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Check this <kbd>[CodeViper Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3YJEAe)</kbd>

#### PHP

```
<?php
    $objects=
    Array
    (
        '1397300927159026' => Array
            (
                'category' => 2,
                'locale' => 'de_DE'
            ),
        '10152395537445743' => Array
            (
                'category' => 100,
                'locale' => 'en_US'
            )
    );
        

    $arr = array();
    foreach($objects as $key => $value) {
        $arr[$key] = $value['locale'];
    }
    
    print_r($arr);
?>
```

#### Result

```
Array ( [1397300927159026] => de_DE [10152395537445743] => en_US )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with a `foreach loop` and a `new array`.

Declare a new `array` say `$abc`

```
<?php

$abc = array();

//Going to loop through original array ($objects) as key and values.

foreach($objects as $key => $val ) {

    // $key will contain values 1397300927159026, 10152395537445743
    // $val['category'] contain values 2,100 
    // $val['locale'] contain values de_DE, en_US

    $abc[$key] = $val['locale'];
}

print_r($abc);
?>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief to make it more useful for original author and other readers.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto i will do

Answer (score 0):

Replace each subarray with its last element's value?  `array_map()` with `end()` is pretty succinct ...though it requires your application to keep the element at the end of the subarrays -- so arguably less trustworthy.

Also `$objects` is a poor variable name choice for a multidimensional array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tiKNM))

```
var_export(array_map('end', $objects));
```

Output:

```
array (
  1397300927159026 => 'de_DE',
  10152395537445743 => 'en_US',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The built in array_column() function does exactly what you need.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php